# Link data to unique index in another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an table **phone_numbers** and table **people**

People structure is

```
id | name
```

phone_numbers structure is

```
id | people_id | phone_number
```

I have seen there is possible to make make an people_id as a link to table **people** in PhpMyAdmin. I would like to know how to realise this.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you think it's right. We are expecting this from you. Don't just ask and go away.

Comment: @TahaPaksu sorry, didn't think about this. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called **foreign keys**, and you can find a lot of tutorials on the internet. 
For example;

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

To show you an example:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   name varchar(255) not null,       
);

CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
   people_id int not null,
   phone_number varchar(32) not null,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_ppkey(people_id)
   REFERENCES people(id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

These lines:

```
FOREIGN KEY fk_ppkey(people_id) REFERENCES people(id)
```

Reference the **id** field of the **people** table to **people_id** table of **phone_numbers** table.